# How to edit and return a Cursor in plpgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, record

I am doing a simple query inside a function, and I need to change the values ​​of this query, but only for information. I don't need to update the table as such. I managed to edit the values ​​but I don't know how to return them.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setDetails(INTEGER,INTEGER) RETURNS TABLE (
    id INTEGER, 
    name TEXT,      
    subsidy TEXT,
    stratum_id NUMERIC, 
    price TEXT, 
    total FLOAT
 ) AS $$
  DECLARE
        service Record;
        subscibed_services Record;
  BEGIN
for service in SELECT services.*, false as subscribed, (CAST(services.price AS float) - CAST(services.subsidy AS float)) AS total FROM services WHERE services.stratum_id = $1 loop
 for subscibed_services in SELECT services.id FROM services WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT charge_details.service_id FROM charge_details WHERE charge_details.charge_id = $2) loop 
    if (CAST(subscibed_services.id as INTEGER) = CAST(service.id as INTEGER)) then
        service.subscribed := true;
        EXIT;
    else
        service.total := 0;
    end if;
 end loop;
end loop;
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And below this function will be executed

```
SELECT setDetails(2,6320)
```

[As you can see, the query does not bring me anything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPRQr.png)

I appreciate the help and I apologize for using the google translator: D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some result from table function, you should to fill related variables (defined inside `table` clause list), and then you should to use `RETURN NEXT` statement. It is well described by [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

Simple example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(n int)
 RETURNS TABLE(a int, b int)
AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. n
  LOOP
    a := i; b := i + 1;
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM foo(10);
```

Your code has another performance bug. Two nested loops over queries can be slow. You can use `JOIN` (in this case self join), and iterate over one cycle instead nested two.